# GCM for app-engine on android studio not compiling

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle, google-cloud-messaging

I have been migrating my project from Eclipse to Android Studio. For my GCM, my server code is not compiling and the import cannot be found for

```
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;
```

Does anyone know the gradle compile line to include? The [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html) have no suggestion. They have a suggestion for the client side as

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+"
```

I need one for my app-engine server.

Comment: `com.google.android.gcm` is deprecated